# How to change the prometheus-client port to desired port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prometheus

The prometheus server will read the metrics from my rails application by reading the http://localhost:3000/metrics endpoint, which I have exposed for metrics generation using the **prometheus-client** gem. Actually, as seen below, it is running by default using the default rails port 3000.

```
http://localhost:3000/metrics
```

How can I change the /metrics port to the port I want it to be? meaning the rails application should run on the default 3000 port and the /metrics endpoint should run on the selected port.

Thanks

Comment: Weird, the default is 5123. How are you running it?

Comment: No, it won't run on the 5123 port.It will run on the 3000 port, which is the default port on Rails. The /metrics end point (target) is actually what I'm providing from the rails application(using prometheus-client gem). This target (http:localhost:3000/metrics) endpoint will be used by Prometheus server in order to get the rails application metrics.

Comment: So how are you running your server?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want your Rails Application to listen to another port. prometheus-client gem does not proved port itself. The listener is Puma (nowadays). So you need to configure your Rails application to reach your goal.
You may run your rails server:

```
rails s -p 5123
```

or make it default by adding

```
# config/puma.rb
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 5123 }
```